# natbib=true with Biblatex gives brackets when command \citetext{\citealp{}} is used

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I'm using biblatex with natbib enabled. I would like to insert some text into multiple citations using `\citetext` as:

```
\citetext{\citep{Ginsburg:1988ie}; but see \citep{Allik:1991ft}}
```

which gives me:

> ([Ginsburg & Nicholls, 1988]; but see [Allik, Tuulmets, & Vos, 1991])

However, I would like square brackets deleted. Anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you just go with `\parencites{Ginsburg:1988ie}[but see][]{Allik:1991ft}`? Or use `\citetext{\cite{Ginsburg:1988ie}; but see \cite{Allik:1991ft}} `? Both yield the same output, while the first is arguably more `biblatex`-idiomatic. If you need more help, an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) might be in order.

Comment: Use `\citealp` instead of `\citep` to suppress the brackets.

Comment: Thank you so much moewe! \parencites works like a charm :), but \citetext\cite although gives nice format, it doesn't replace "and" with "&" as required by APA for parenthesis citation. \parencites does change it. Thank you again!

Comment: Mico \citealp also doesn't convert "and" to "&" when used with \citetext.

Comment: The issue of `&` vs `and` seems to be related to `biblatex-apa` treating parenthetical citations and other citations differently, `\parencites` then is a parenthetical citation while `\citetext{\cite` and `\citetext{\citealp` are not (for `biblatex` that is).

Comment: @moewe - In other words, is this a bug in `biblatex`'s emulation of the `\citealp` macro?

Comment: @Gaijin - Have you tried `(\citealp{Ginsburg:1988ie}; but see \citealp{Allik:1991ft})`, i.e., replacing `\citetext` with hard-coded parentheses?

Comment: @Mico It depends how you look at it, I suppose. If you think of `\citealp` as being `\citep` minus the parentheses you might expect it to behave like `\citep` in any other respect (save for the parentheses), but `biblatex` makes `\citealp` an alias for `\cite` (which is also reasonable considering the output one gets normally - and generally probably not worth the hassle). This together with `biblatex-apa` distinguishing between parenthetical citations and normal ones (by redefining `\parencite`) gives the result.

Comment: @moewe - `biblatex` does a good job emulating `natbib`'s  `\citet` and `\citep` macros. Why not also emulate `\citealp` (and, possibly, `\citealt`) equally well? I don't understand why making `\citealp` an alias for `\cite` might be considered to be a "reasonable" emulation strategy.

Comment: @Mico - I've tried the hardcoding strategy, doesn't change "and" to "&". The only command that properly works is \parencite.

Comment: @Gaijin - Glad the `\parencite` method works for you. With some luck, biblatex's emulation of the `\citealp` macro will one day be modified to produce the correct output as well. :-)

Comment: @Mico - let's hope so, full emulation of the natbib commands would be great.