# Biblatex natbib option kills \citeauthor* (starred)?

Tags: biblatex

My `texdoc biblatex` states:

> \citeauthor[ prenote ][ postnote ]{ key }
>   \citeauthor*[ prenote ][ postnote ]{ key }
>   ... The starred variants effectively force maxcitenames to 1 for just this command on so only print the first name in the labelname list (potentially followed by the “et al” string if there are more names).

So I'm trying this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%
  natbib,% just loads citep, citey?
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true, % in ieee.bbx, bbx:isbn controls both isbn and issn
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter

Test 1: \citeauthor{westfahl:space}, *: \citeauthor*{westfahl:space},

Test 2: \citeauthor{baez/article}, *: \citeauthor*{baez/article},

Test 3: \citeauthor{companion}, *: \citeauthor*{companion},

Test 4: \citeauthor{cotton}, *: \citeauthor*{cotton},

\end{document}
```

If I comment the `natbib,` option line and compile (`pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`+), then I get the output as expected:

[image: test1.png]

But if I leave the natbib option uncommented, as in the MWE, and I compile - then I get this:

[image: test2.png]

... that is, something happened, so the `\citeauthor*` command also outputs all names, instead of only the first one (+ optionally et al.).
Why does this happen - and how can I get the original behavior of `\citeauthor*` back, even if I have loaded the `natbib` option?

Comment: That is by default, apparently `natbib`'s starred variants behave like this. If you have a look at `blx-natbib.def` you will find that the starred versions actually set the `maxnames` counter to 999 in `natbib` compatibility mode (and thus do more or less the opposite of what they normally do). To restore normal behaviour go with `\newrobustcmd*{\citet}{\textcite}`, `\newrobustcmd*{\citep}{\parencite}` etc. pp.

Comment: Incidentally, here is a question where in contrast to your question, where `biblatex` emulates `natbib` too much, the emulation does not go far enough. [`natbib=true` with Biblatex gives brackets when command `\citetext{\citealp{}}` is used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218519/35864)

Comment: Thanks for that @moewe - that explains it; feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it; cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature! Apparently, `natbib`'s starred commands behave like this.

In [`blx-natbib.def`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/blx-natbib.def), the configuration file that is loaded if you issue `natbib=true`, you will find (amongst others)

```
\newrobustcmd*{\citet}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}%
     \textcite}
    {\textcite}}

\newrobustcmd*{\citep}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}%
     \parencite}
    {\parencite}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
  {\defcounter{maxnames}{999}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

So `natbib`'s starred versions in a way do the exact opposite of `biblatex`'s starred versions.
The former sets `maxnames` to 999 to print all names, while the latter  prints just one name.

Depending on whether or not you need `natbib` support you can either cease to use `natbib=true` or selectively restore the behaviour you want - depending on how much you want to restore it might be a better idea to just cherry-pick those definitions from `blx-natbib.def` you want.

If, for example, you only need `\citep` and `\citet`

```
\newrobustcmd*{\citet}{\textcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\citep}{\parencite}
```

is more than enough for you.